# Kind of archive for sold out products

Tags: products

Our magento shop is currently very big and we've got a lot of products. Products that are sold out are being kept in the shop for seo reasons.

In order to minify the database we want to get rid of those sold out products. Is there any plugin of some sort, that creates static html pages of those products? After that we could redirect the old product url to the new static one.

Or do you know any other method to achieve a similar behaviour?

The primary goal is to minify the database while sold out products are still visible for visitors and search engines.

Comment: Why do you want to "minify" the database? For what reason?

Answer (score 0):

Some type of full page cache for sold out products only may work. There are several plugins for this, and you can modify them a bit to not clear storage for sold out products.

Comment: Thank you! That would have an impact on the server performance, that's true. But our main goal is to shrink the database. Any suggestions in that way?

Comment: The idea is not to improve performance.  1. set up cache. it caches out of stock products pages automatically to simple html files.  2. remove sold out products from the database.